# exporting mysql in mamp-not letting me save file as sql?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

This is a weird thing I haven't seen as I'm usually working on a live server.  On my MAMP, when I try and export the database, it just opens the file within phpmyadmin-like as a text document.  I tried to copy the file to a text document with and gave it a .sql at the end, but that gave me an error when trying to import to the live server.  When I try an export from the live server, I get the save location dialog box popping up as normal.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's wrong with little information. What version of phpMyAdmin are you using?

However when you try to export the database, in the export page you'll have a choice between 'Quick' and 'Custom'. Chose custom and under the 'Output' section you'll see two choices.

1. Save output to a file
2. View output as text

Generally 'Save output to a file' is selected by default, but i'm not sure whether something has gone wrong and the other option is selected in your case .

Comment: Had the same issue on MAMP, a text file was displayed to me, followed this answer and now in quick mode, I can download the `.sql` file.

Answer (score 21):

inside of phpmyadmin you'll need to navigate to:

`Setting >> Export >> Export Defaults`

Click on the radio button to "Save as file" (this will be under the Custom header)

Click "Save"

see picture here: 
[image]

Comment: This is the right answer! That solved my problem. After updating Mamp I couldn't save on file anymore with the quick export (by default I mean).

Answer (score 2):

Solved mine by changing Export setting

From "Setting" tab check in "Export" section, you'd find "Save as file" and "Save to browser's storage" radio buttons, choose "Save as file" and click "Go". Restart your WAMP OR MAMP and try to export, it should download this time.

Answer (score 1):

I exported with custom option first, switched back to quick and it worked as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Select the database you wish to export and:

1. click "Custom - display all possible options" under 'export method'.
2. Click "Save output to a file" under 'Output'.
3. Click on 'Go'.

Answer (score 0):

My phpMyAdmin settings **were** already set to export a file; however, I had to change the phpMyAdmin config file `/path/to/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` at approximately line 256:

```
$cfg['Export']['asfile'] = TRUE;
```

*Note:* Check your "format-specific options" when exporting.

*Example:* Columns enclosed with: you may have to replace `&quot;` with quote marks (`"`)

Comment: I think @zEELz's comment is very simple and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Drupal database. Check the size of some tables. I had to empty some cache tables. That worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Jeroen - it may not be the most detailed answer, but "Check the size of some tables. I had to empty some cache tables" is at least an answer.

Answer (score -2):

1. Click on server>Appearance settings>More settings>Export
2. Make sure your export method is set to Quick
3. Check the 'Save as file' then 'Apply' at bottom.